# IntelliJ IDEA 13 cannot resolve method in spring

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

I have annoying issue with following lines of code:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN").
            and().
            formLogin().
            loginPage("/login").
            defaultSuccessUrl("/").
            failureUrl("/login?error").
            loginProcessingUrl("/login").
            successHandler(loginSucessHandler).
            permitAll().
            and().
            logout().
            logoutUrl("/logout").
            logoutSuccessUrl("/").
            invalidateHttpSession(true).
            permitAll();
}
```

Intellij always show me "cannot resolve method formLogin()". I try to reimport projects to regenerete projects from gradle invalidates the cache for intellij but I always get this annoying message. It is possible somehow to get rid of it? If I try to build project from gradle I have no issue so it must be something wrong with intellij idea. Thanks in advance
EDIT: if I run make in intellij it compile project without any issues.

Comment: try closing the intellij project, cleaning all idea files *.iml and .idea directory, close the project and then reimport. as you say if you can build it in command line with graddle then it has to be a problem with the intellij setup

Comment: I already try it but id doesn't work.

Comment: File a bug wth them, normally pretty quick to fix

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. It probably has to do with the generic types being returned. Don't know if this is something the IDE can handle as the info it needs is probably only available at runtime. (btw - one can replicate this just by opening the form-jc sample that comes with spring-security).